# Kolab 3.4 free way to integrate with Outlook 2010 as Exchange Replacement?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I just successfully installed Kolab 3.4 on a CentOS 7 server. Everything worked out well.

Now how can I use this as a exchange replacement?
Is there a reliable free connector? Or do I have to pay?
There is ActiveSync compatibility, but I dont know how to connect Outlook 2010 with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveSync with KolabNow and Outlook 2013. With Outlook 2010 and Kolab you'll be able to use IMAP and/or WebDAV.

You can find more details on [Kolab website](https://kolabnow.com/clients/outlook).